# How to output BSON document with invalid datetime field from mongoDB query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to extract all mongoDB documents that match a particular query using pymongo and a for loop however somewhere in the batch of documents returned from my query there's an invalid datetime format (i.e. year 20109 is out of range) which causes an InvalidBSON exception to be thrown. Is there a way for me to try to output that document, perhaps as a string or json, so that I can use that as a reference to troubleshoot the issue at the source?

I'm using python 3.6 and have tried pymongo 3.8 and pymongo 3.5.1. This doesn't seem to be an issue for an older version of the code that I used previously which was using python 2.7 and pymongo 3.5.1.

This is an example of the invalid BSON document that is causing me issue:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b37c235efe6c626cd28a24f"),
  "datePayment" : Date(572428785600000),
  "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-06-30T17:48:19.352Z"),
  "updatedOn" : ISODate("2018-06-30T17:48:19.352Z")
}
```

I expect to have a string or json version of this document to be captured somewhere so that I can use this to trace back the issue at the source and fix it